# WCF 4: Default Throttling Settings for WCF Services

Tags: wcf

I was reading [Wenlong Dong's blog article about the default throttling settings for WCF services in WCF 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx), and have a question about the values for the default settings:

> MaxConcurrentSessions: default is 100 * **ProcessorCount**
>
> MaxConcurrentCalls: default is 16 * **ProcessorCount**
>
> MaxConcurrentInstances: default is the total of the above two, which
>   follows the same pattern as before.

Does **ProcessorCount** refer to:

1. The number of physical CPUs/sockets
2. The number of physical cores across all CPUs
3. The number of logical cores, if hyperthreading is enabled?

Thanks,

-- Patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processor count means logical cores. The value is actually the value supplied by **System.Environment.ProcessorCount**

Comment: If hyperthreading is enabled, you will see cores*2. For example, on my i7 machine ProcessorCount is 8, and according to that the throttling is set.

Comment: I have this value = 2.
I added to behaviors this line
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentInstances="1000"/>
then I open this setting and read other two values, they are 16 and 100
but if it's multiplied on processor count from environment it would be 32 and 200
why I see defaults as 16 and 100?

getting tow other values in this way
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");

Answer (score 1):

Here are some stuff from MSDN that might be helpful.
Optimizing WCF Web Service Performance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377061(v=bts.10).aspx

ServiceThrottlingBehavior Members:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentsessions(v=vs.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior_members(v=vs.90).aspx

Cheers

Comment: From the first article: "Set maxConcurrentCalls, maxConcurrentSessions, and maxConcurrentInstances to a value greater than 16 * **the number of CPUs or CPU cores**.". Their example implies it's the number of cores, but is it the physical cores, or logical cores?